# Apps slows down when mongoose model is instantiated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing the shopping cart as part of my learning. I'm facing the issue that whenever items are added to the cart, the loading time increases tremendously (benchmark below) and back to normal when cart is empty.

---

**Benchmark**
when cart is empty: loading time below 1s.

```
GET / 304 154.242 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.css 304 81.079 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 79.363 ms - -
GET /fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 304 84.550 ms - -
GET /product/58c179fb2148643f5865d4ca/image 304 86.347 ms - -
GET /product/58c151f95b18373990f1c714/image 304 113.943 ms - -
GET /product/58c17c9e32f18e2eb86fbd44/image 304 120.220 ms - -
GET /product/58c17ced9697ec3e44bba381/image 304 82.483 ms - -
GET /product/58c210c5e5ca5b2298724b77/image 304 83.583 ms - -
GET /fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 304 15.826 ms - -
```

when items are in the cart: loading time is on average 10s.

```
GET / 304 3441.581 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.css 304 17074.679 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 18020.767 ms - -
GET /fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 304 19067.181 ms - -
GET /product/58c17c9e32f18e2eb86fbd44/image 304 13065.619 ms - -
GET /product/58c151f95b18373990f1c714/image 304 15917.767 ms - -
GET /product/58c179fb2148643f5865d4ca/image 304 22550.998 ms - -
GET /product/58c17ced9697ec3e44bba381/image 304 23376.352 ms - -
GET /product/58c210c5e5ca5b2298724b77/image 304 20143.963 ms - -
GET /fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 304 4767.430 ms - -
```

---

The code below is minimal implementation:

**models/product.js**

```
var schema = new Schema({
  image: {data: Buffer, contentType: String},
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  description: {type: String, required: true},
  price: {type: Number, required: true}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

**models/cart.js**

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
// associative array
  this.items = oldCart.items || {};

  this.add = function(product) {
// if item is not in cart => assign argument to product properties
    if(!this.items[product._id])
      this.items[product._id] = {product: product, qty: 0, price: 0};
// if item is already in cart => just increase the qty and price
    this.items[product._id].qty++;
    this.items[product._id].price += product.price;
  }


  this.removeItems = function (productId) {
    delete this.items[productId];
  }
}
```

**routes/cart.js**

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  var productId = req.params.id;
// req.session from: express-session module
  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);

  Product.findById(productId, function (err, product) {

    cart.add(product);

    req.session.cart = cart;
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});


router.get('/remove/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  var productId = req.params.id;
  var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);

  cart.removeItems(productId);

  req.session.cart = cart;
  res.redirect('/cart');
});
```

---

**Tries:**
I had tried to set unneeded objects to `null` by my guess that memory may be leaked somewhere. Problem still persisted.

---

The product images are not greater that 16MB, so I stored them in mongo as BinaryData. I really have no ideas how the load time increases. Every suggestion is appreciated. I'm willing to edit the post to give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably caused by your image buffer being loaded when you find your product by id.

```
...
image: {data: Buffer, contentType: String},
...
```

Since you don't need that information when adding to cart, on your find by id, tell mongo not to return that field.

```
Product.findById(productId).select('-image').exec(function(){})
```

Then maybe when someone looks at their cart have another call for retrieving the images.

**EDIT:**

Make sure you are also caching the image when retrieving the images. This will make sure your server can serve the images quickly.

See [apicache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apicache), it should be able todo what you need.

On the client side, you may need to make sure your images are being cached there as well (this might already occur automatically).

**Edit 2:**
I believe something like this should work for you for the apicache. You may need to tweak it a bit.

```
var apicache = require('apicache');
let cache = apicache.middleware;

...

app.get('/image/:productId', cache('1 hour'), function(req, response) {
  var buffer = ""; //get the image buffer from mongo

  //return to client
  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' //Or whatever filetype its supposed to be... png, gif etc
  });
  response.write(buffer);
  response.end();
});

...
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it solved my issue. My another doubt is if it's because of loading buffer, then only request/code involving cart i.e add to card & view cart will be slowed down. However, the issue is whenever items are in the cart the loadtime of entire apps increases including homepage, signin, signup, etc.

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD I'd think that the whole app was slow because you were storing the image buffer in a session variable and each time the app reloads it has to load in the whole image buffer again. Just a thought. Could be wrong. Maybe try clearning your session after making sure you aren't storing that data there.

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD Whoops. I see what you mean now. Maybe see if there is a way to cache that image information for the client, so they only need to load the image once. Your server side route for grabbing the image, can do the caching, [Checkout APICache Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apicache)

Comment: I took a look at documentation. Where should I place the cache?

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD See my last edit. :) You'll definitely need to add more to it, but it should get you started.

Comment: @NERDYLIZARD Would really appriciate it if you marked this answer as the solution. :) If you need any other help. Let me know!